# Pass opaque LUA data through C++

Tags: c++, c, lua, luajit

I have the following scenario: A LUA function *LuaFuncA* calls a C++ function *CPPFunc* and passes an argument *Arg*, which is opaque to the CPP function and could be anything (whether nil, number, userdata etc.) and cannot be assumed to be of the same type each time *CPPFunc* is called.

*LuaFuncA* then terminates and only C++ code is running. After a certain amount of time (which could be anything, from milliseconds to hours) *CPPFunc* needs to call another LUA function *LuaFuncB* and pass *Arg*.

Attempting the native solution of using `lua_getpointer(L, 1)` then pushing it back with `lua_pushlightuserdata(L, 1)` (L seems to be the same handle in both calls) results in the following error:

`attempt to index local 'Arg' (a userdata value).`

(in this case Arg was `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and I attempted to print `Arg[2]`)

Thank you for any advice!

EDIT: `CPPFunc` is a task scheduler routine. `LuaFuncA` basically registers `LuaFuncB` as a task, from which point `CPPFunc` need to call `LuaFuncB` at regular intervals, which means that the state must be either preserved or recreated before each call.

EDIT 2: The program is cross-platform and must be able to run natively on both Linux and Windows, therefore platform specific calls such as fork() cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Lua registry and reference mechanism for this. With *Arg* on top of the stack, do `int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);`. That will pop it and save it to the registry, with `ref` being your key to retrieve it later. You can then save `ref` as you would any other `int` in C or C++. To retrieve *Arg* and push it back onto the stack, do `lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref);`. If you won't need to retrieve it again, do `luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref);` to clean up after yourself.

Comment: This mostly worked! The only issue is with Lunar objects but I guess I could work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling Lua functions from C/C++, you must have at least one `lua_State`, where the value in question is.

If during "LuaFuncA then terminates and only C++ code is running" you still keep that state around until you need the value again, then you don't need to change anything. Simply remember the index at which the value is, then access it again when needed, e.g. with `lua_pushvalue` to get it toward the top for a `lua_call`.

If you do "use up" the value at some point (i.e. you call a function that pops it), then you can create a copy with `lua_pushvalue` and move it down the stack with `lua_insert` to an index where it can stay until later.

And if you can't keep the original state around, then you can simply create a separate one with `lua_newstate`, move your value (or a copy) to that state with `lua_xmove`, and later move it back to any other state when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

I can't keep the original state since the C++ program reuses the same state over and over and is too complex to redesign.
`lua_xmove` mostly works but there's a different issue here - `LuaFuncB` actually needs to be called multiple times (`CPPFunc` is actually a task schedule which runs different callbacks at regular intervals). Since both `lua_xmove` and `lua_pcall` pop the arguments from the stack, the result is that `LuaFuncB` only runs properly the first time.

Comment: As mentioned, you can create copies of a value with `lua_pushvalue`. So if you need to copy a value to a different state, instead of moving it, that's just "copy, then move the copy", i.e. `lua_pushvalue` + `lua_xmove`.